# How to mirror and repeat periodic function from a .csv file

Tags: gnuplot

I have several .csv files with a half of a symetrical periodic fuction. What's the best way to plot a file, mirror it and then repeat origial and the mirror until end of x_range?
Edit:
Now I realised how to do it, but i am still intrested if there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
stats "KWV [100] прод.DAT" using 1 name "A"
stats "KWV [111] прод.DAT" using 1 name "B"
stats "KWV [100] поп.DAT" using 1 name "C"
stats "KWV [111] поп.DAT" using 1 name "D"
plot for [i = 0:3] "KWV [100] прод.DAT" using (i*2*A_max+ $1):2 with lines lc "green" notitle,for [i = 0:3] "KWV [100] прод.DAT" using ((i*2+2)*A_max-$1):2 with lines lc "green" notitle, keyentry with lines lc "green" title "[100] Продольные", for [i = 0:3] "KWV [111] прод.DAT" using (i*2*B_max+$1):2 with lines lc "red" notitle,for [i = 0:3] "KWV [111] прод.DAT" using ((i*2+2)*B_max-$1):2 with lines lc "red" notitle, keyentry with lines lc "red" title "[111] Продольные", for [i = 0:3] "KWV [100] поп.DAT" using (i*2*C_max+$1):2 with lines lc "blue" notitle,for [i = 0:3] "KWV [100] поп.DAT" using ((i*2+2)*C_max-$1):2 with lines lc "blue" notitle, keyentry with lines lc "blue" title "[100] Поперечные", for [i = 0:3] "KWV [111] поп.DAT" using (i*2*D_max+$1):2 with lines lc "magenta" notitle,for [i = 0:3] "KWV [111] поп.DAT" using ((i*2+2)*D_max-$1):2 with lines lc "magenta" notitle, keyentry with lines lc "magenta" title "[111] Поперечные"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Well, you are not giving to many details. Actually, it is kind of expected to provide some code and detailed description of the problem. Can you give a minimal (non-)working example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for providing some code. However, I'm still not sure whether you just want to repeat the original data in positive direction and repeat the mirrored data in negative direction, instead of flipping the data for every repetition in both directions? A sketch would help.

Comment: in order to illustrate: if your data is axially symmetric like `A`, there will be no difference `AAAAAA`. If your data might be asymmetric to zero, like `E`, it would be `3E3E3E3`, if you see `3` as mirror data of `E`. (and plotting `333EEEE` is probably not intended).

Comment: any response would be appreciated and would be considered as kind of minimum politeness...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are not giving too many details. Depending on what exactly you want, this could be one approach.

**Code:**

```
### horizontal mirroring of data
reset session

# create some test data 
# curve from here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html
set table $Data
    plot sample [t=0:pi:0.1] '+' u (16*sin(t)**3 + 3):(13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t)) w table
unset table

set size ratio -1
set xrange [-25:25]
set grid xtics, ytics
xm = 3   # mirror axis

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red" title "Original", \
     '' u (-($1-xm)+xm):2 w lp pt 7 lc "green" title "Mirror"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: of course `(-($1-xm)+xm)` can be shortened to `(-$1+2*xm)`, but the first way is maybe easier to follow what's going on with shifting and mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

Providing code in the question is always helpful, even better if possible with some data and/or illustration.
Well, at least there is a way to present your gnuplot code more readable, i.e. breaking lines by using `\` as the last character in a line (no other characters allowed afterwards in the same line).

Although you are not explicitely writing it, I assume your data is axially symmetric relative to x=0 (well, example `$DataD` is chosen central symmetric).
It depends what you consider "more elegant", at least you can make it a bit shorter such that you don't have to double the plot commands. You can define a function `Mirror(i) = i<0 ? -1 : 1` which is `-1` for negative arguments and `+1` otherwise. Furthermore, you can add arrows to indicate the borders `A_max`, etc. (I assume these are crystallographic unit cells in your case).

**Edit:**
In case you want to flip your data (especially `$DataD`) for every repetition then simply define a function `Flip(i) = i%2 ? -1 : +1`.

Check out the following minimal example *with data* and *with graph*.

**Code:**

```
### periodic repetition of data
reset session

# create some test data
set table $DataA
    plot sample [-pi:pi] '+' u 1:(x**2/9) w table
set table $DataB
    plot sample [-pi:pi] '+' u 1:(cos(x)+3) w table
set table $DataC
    plot sample [-pi:pi] '+' u 1:(abs(x)/2+5) w table
set table $DataD
    plot sample [-pi:pi] '+' u 1:((x**3+x**2)/40+8) w table
unset table

stats $DataA u 1 name "A" nooutput
stats $DataB u 1 name "B" nooutput
stats $DataC u 1 name "C" nooutput
stats $DataD u 1 name "D" nooutput

set key out
do for [i=-4:3] {
    set arrow i+100 from first (2*i+1)*A_max, graph 0 to first (2*i+1)*A_max, graph 1 nohead dt 2
}
Mirror(i) = i<0 ? -1 : 1
Flip(i) = i%2 ? -1 : +1

plot for [i=-3:3] $DataA u ((i*2)*A_max + Mirror(i)*$1):2 w l lc "green" notitle, \
        keyentry w l lc "green" title "DataA", \
     for [i=-3:3] $DataB u ((i*2)*B_max + Mirror(i)*$1):2 w l lc "red" notitle, \
        keyentry w l lc "red" title "DataB", \
     for [i=-3:3] $DataC u ((i*2)*C_max + Mirror(i)*$1):2 w l lc "blue" notitle, \
        keyentry w l lc "blue" title "DataC", \
     for [i=-3:3] $DataD u ((i*2)*D_max + Mirror(i)*$1):2 w l lc "magenta" notitle, \
        keyentry w l lc "magenta" title "DataD", \
     for [i=-3:3] $DataD u ((i*2)*D_max + Flip(i)*$1):($2+2) w l lc "orange" notitle, \
        keyentry w l lc "orange" title "DataD flipped"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]